# SUM of the column in foreach array PHP not working

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum, calculation

I have created the foreach function and inside of that function, I am trying to calculate the sum of the column.
I have read all the related threads on StackOverflow or google, but for 3 days I am trying and I could not get the answer and resolved my issue.
Please help me, how I calculate the column, I want to SUM of all `[cost]` and show in `[total]`.

Please help me.

```
table = table1
    ID | key    | p_name
    ---------------------
    1  | 123456 | A
    2  | 145236 | B

table = table2
    ID | column | key
    ---------------------
    1  | 10     | 123456
    2  | 5      | 123456
    3  | 20     | 145236
    4  | 30     | 145236
```

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1`");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$final = [];
foreach ($result as $data => $value) {
    $stmt01 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1`");
    $stmt01->execute();
    if($stmt01->rowCount() > 0) {
        while($result001 = $stmt01->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $name = $result001['p_name'];

            $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT `ID`, SUM(`column`) AS `last_cost_rate`, `key` FROM `table2` WHERE `key` = :key AND `ID` = (SELECT MAX(`ID`) FROM `table2` WHERE `key` = :key)");
            $sql->execute(array(':key' => $value['key']));
            $sum = 0;
            while($sqlvalue001 = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $last_costing = $sqlvalue001['last_cost_rate'];
                $sum+=$last_costing
            }

        }
    }

    
    $final[] = [
        'name' => $name,
        'total' => $sum
    ];              
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => A
            [total] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => B
            [total] => 30
        )
)
```

Comment: One simple way is to use another query to "select sum(last_cost_rate) as totalsum from [tablename]" and get the value first, then put this figure as the value of the total key

Comment: This code won't run as you are missing a `$` when setting `last_costing`.

Comment: It was the typos @NigelRen, otherwise it giving the output

Comment: @KenLee I am not understanding please helping to prove the answer sir,,pls

Comment: Do not nest queries like this.  Do not write `prepare()` inside of a loop.  `$final['cost']` does not exist -- the `$final` array is an indexed array of associative arrays.  Don't fix this code; throw it away.  Refactor your snippet to use a `JOIN`.

Comment: What is `$result`? Show your table schemas.  We need a [mcve].  Show your expected result from a small but relevant sample of data. This whole thing needs to be rebuilt.  Give us a db fiddle demo.

Comment: `$result` has one query too which help I getting some column data. What is in $result this not an issue? We can understand by the code that some query also above the $result.
The issue is calculating.

Comment: while($sqlvalue001 = $sqlresult001->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $last_costing = $sqlvalue001['last_cost_rate'];
                    
                    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(last_cost_rate) as totalSum FROM `material_in`");
                    $sql->execute();
                    while($sqlvalue = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $total_costing = $sqlvalue['totalSum'];
                    }
                } - Its is not working @KenLee

Comment: Sir I dont know how to implement and what you said, How I make it fixed

Comment: As @mickmackusa has said, please show the table structure (with a few data items) of the table1 and table2 so that we can further advise (for sure using join is better than using iterations to extract/process the data between two tables, but please let us know the details first).

Comment: @Sidharth it is DEFINITELY worth complying with the above requests from volunteers.  You stand to benefit greatly from solid advice that will improve your understanding of programming.  Not to mention that your application will run more efficiently, be easier to read, and will be easier to maintain. **100% worth it!**

Comment: I have been update the question. Please answer I am trying this type of answer

Comment: Did u miss out the totalsum key-value pair in your revised output ? (Or it is no longer needed?)

Comment: I make the code as much I know, sir if you think this is requred please fiddle me

Comment: Ideally, a [mcve] contains enough data to show qualifying and non-qualifying data -- this helps to prove some answers as "incorrect".

Comment: We don't know what is in `$result` and there is insufficient sample data provided in your table mockup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have build the array, just use a foreach block to replace all the sumtotal :

So you may continue to use the following:

```
$sum += $last_costing;
```

and then use the following foreach to populate the data:

```
foreach ($final as &$value) {
$value['sumtotal'] = $sum;
}
```

So, the code (fully working) is:

```
<?php
// Note: put your real username/password in the following line :

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","dbname");

$sql="select table1.p_name, table1.`key` , table2.`column` from table1, table2 where table1.`key`=table2.`key` order by table1.id, table2.id desc";

$final = [];
$sum=0;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$opname="";
    while ($c = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if ($opname!=$c["p_name"]) {
          $opname=$c["p_name"];  


      $last_costing=$c["column"];

      $sum += $last_costing;

         $final[] = [
        'product' => $c["p_name"],
        'total' => $c["column"],
        'sumtotal' => 0
         ];      
      }
  }

foreach ($final as &$value) {
$value['sumtotal'] = $sum;
}

print_r($final);
?>
```

The result is:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
      ( 
      [product] => A 
      [total] => 5 
      [sumtotal] => 35 
      ) 
    [1] => Array 
      ( 
       [product] => B 
       [total] => 30 
       [sumtotal] => 35 
      ) 
)
```

Comment: thank you for answering but this code is really tough to understand

Comment: this there any way to sum of `$sum+=$last_costing` in my code - this solution will also resolve my issue

Comment: @Sidharth , I have found a way to use `$sum+=$last_costing` to do the job , please see my revised answer (Please note that some of your original codes are problematic and so have to be rewritten) - now the code should not be too tough to understand